# a formal way of creating a UI from a set of functions?

Tags: android, guidelines, transitions

I am working on an application that has a number of functions and features with the intention of launching it first on Android and then on iOS.

Coming from a development background with minimal design experience, I found it really hard to visualize how the application would work as a whole.

I have an idea about how each function would look on its own but when it comes to moving between screens and how to connect them is puzzling me. Is there a formal guideline or rules to help ?

Comment: Android http://developer.android.com/design/index.html iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1

Comment: you should do some more research on your project until you get clear idea that how one module will interact with other. I had same experience but I research until I feel that now its feasible to make the screen. For this refer pinterest, dribble, behance. Because without knowing subject of your project we can't help you  more so it better to search UI  examples with appropriate tag from the sites which I mention here.

Comment: can you post this an answer?

Comment: Where is the UX designer on your project team???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a couple of documents that guide you in this process, or if not then a UX designer will be quite handy.

I have found that a comprehensive "Design Framework" will cover all of the applicable standards and guidelines that are required for you to implement the functional requirements, but if not then someone will have to do the interpretation. But if it is not documented then the next person might interpret it in a completely different way (remember agile means document what you need, not that you can do without).

[image]

I think what you are looking for is something that will bridge the development and interaction design guide, which ties the UI components and the UI patterns together to explain how the functions are implemented as the front-end interface that the user interacts with.